# MSBuild task to Copy contents of a specific folder by using a wild card in the path

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019, msbuild-task

My Folder structure is as follows

```
Module
-->Asia - 1.0.0.12
------>Deployment
------>Install.exe
------>version.xml
-->Africa - 1.0.3.4
------>Deployment
------>Install.exe
------>version.xml
-->Europe - 2.0.1.2
------>Deployment
------>Install.exe
------>version.xml
```

I want to copy the 'deployment' folder (and subfolders) under each region to my output directory. The region numbers will change so i cannot hardcode them in my Include statement. The command i am using to copy for Asia region is

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <GetFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Module\Asia*\Deployment\**\*">
            <Destination>D:\Region\Asia</Destination>
        </GetFiles >
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="%(GetFiles.Identity)"
        DestinationFolder="%(GetFiles.Destination)\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />
```

Instead of the Deployment folder and its subdirectories getting copied under the Destination, i am getting the folder structure as

```
D:\Region\Asia\Asia - 1.0.0.12\Deployment
```

what i want is

```
D:\Region\Asia\Deployment
```

Can this be achieved? Thanks

Comment: Actually, this is a special feature of wildcards in MSBuild Copy Task, so you can't avoid them unless you specify the full name of Asia-1.0.0.12 to get what you deserve. If you have other folders, you should add another `<GetFiles Include="xxxx">....</GetFiles >` node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MSBuild task to Copy contents of a specific folder by using a wild
> card in the path

If you use wildcard in msbuild and do a copy task, the MSBuild will always copy the path from the first address where the wildcard is used.

For your situation, since you just use wildcard under `Asia*`, so it will keep `Asia - 1.0.0.12\Deployment` folder structure under `D:\Region\Asia`.

**As a suggestion**, to get what you want, you need to clearly indicate the name of the **Asia** folder, even if it is much more complicated, you need to specify one by one.

Use like this:

```
    <Target Name="xxx" BeforeTargets="Build">
      <ItemGroup>
            <GetFiles Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Module\Asia - 1.0.0.12\Deployment\**\*">
                <Destination>D:\Region\Asia</Destination>
            </GetFiles>
     </ItemGroup>
     <Copy SourceFiles="%(GetFiles.Identity)"
           DestinationFolder="%(GetFiles.Destination)\Deployment\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
    
   </Target>
```